# Compare-Object resulting in incorrect results

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

When trying to use `Compare-Object` for two lists of PC names, the result is a list of server names from one item, and `System.Object[]` for the other. Both items are of type string, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

My two lists names are `$SCC`, and `$windowsWorkstations`. When I run `$SCC`, it returns a list of PC names. When I run `$windowsWorkstations.Name`, it also returns a list of PC names. Both are of type String.

To clarify, `$windowsWorkstations` is type `object`, but `$windowsWorkstations.Name` is type `String`.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SCC -DifferenceObject $windowsWorkstations.Name -IncludeEqual
```

The result is a list that contains all PC names from `$SCC` with `=>` as the side indicator. The last item on the list is `System.Object[]` with `<=` as the side indicator.

```
InputObject     SideIndicator
-----------     -------------
PC53127         =>
System.Object[] <=
```

Notice I shortened the result of the Compare-Object as there are 15,000+ PC names on `$SCC`. I used only 1 as an example.

What would make the result of this compare be `System.Object[]`? Can you not compare `psobjects`?

Comment: the indicators show that `PC53127` is only in the `$windowsWorkstations.Name` collection while the `System.Object[]` is only in the `$SCC` collection. so ... have you fully reviewed content of that collection? it seems you have something in it that is not what you expect ...

Comment: That makes more sense. I thought it was $windowsWorkstation that was having the issue, not $SCC. I think the issue is that I'm converting $SCC.ToString() prior to comparing, resulting in the System.Object[]. Can you compare an Object[] with a String? Every time I try it, it starts to run and never stops.

Comment: How do you get the content for the lists? `Get-Content`/`Import-Csv`,`ConvertFrom-*`? You do append the `.Name` property to `$windowsWorkstations` but not to `$SCC`

Comment: @JK72 - you will need to look into the structure of `$SCC`. try the usual - feed it to `Get-Member` first and look over that. then feed `$SCC[0]` to `Select-Object -Property *` and review the result. that otta give you the specific property you wan to compare against your string values in the other collection.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ToString()` on an object gives you a string representation of that object. In many cases that string representation is just the object's type name. In your particular case `$SCC` appears to be an object array, so calling `ToString()` on it gives you the type name `System.Object[]`.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $v = Get-ChildItem
PS C:\> $v.ToString()
System.Object[]
```

If the elements of `$SCC` are strings the comparison from your question should do just fine. Simply don't convert `$SCC` to a string first.

If the elements of `$SCC` are not strings you need to update your question with more information about the content of that variable.